# Can I type \LaTeX inside inline code in Rmarkdown?

Tags: symbols, r, knitr, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I know I can use $$ to write `\LaTeX` in Rmarkdown documents like $\beta$. My goal is if this is possible inside inline code.

I would do `` `$\beta$` `` or `` `$\\beta$` ``, but both do not work.

In case it is not possible, is there some way to generate a greek letter inside inline code in Rmarkdown?

Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821326/how-can-i-write-special-characters-in-rmarkdown-latex-documents, I tried `` `&beta;` ``.

But it also does not work. What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: A greek letter beta highlighted just as (and together other) verbatim code, as in Rmarkdown, markdown or here is done with two backticks, one at the beginning and other at the end of the `highlighted expression`.

Comment: Have you tried to simply use the unicode character (and an appropriate font) within backticks?

Comment: Yes, I tried the unicode character instead of &beta; (without changing anything about the font; how should I do?), but not success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found that it depends on the type of area you are working in and potentially easier if your target is to show it in html rather than pdf so within a code chunk I got best success with `<code><mathml><mi>&#x03B2;</mi></mathml></code>`

Whereas outside a code chunk I found I had to simply use

## `β`

[image]

Note the highlighted `β`

Answer (score 2):

The inline code is to show code verbatim, not to "interpret" that code. What you want is completely contradictory. So you have two options:

```
  1. Text with `in line` $\beta$ `code`  or ...

  2. Text with \texttt{in line $\beta$ code}.
```

Comment: Alternately just highlight an imbedded beta ` β ` `β`

Comment: @KJO Maybe with some additional work in the YAML header,  but in this  Rmarkdown *as i*s that only produce  a fatal error with pdflatex (cannot  manage U+03B2) or it is silently omitted with xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: OK I just ran \beta inside rstudio to generate the preview symbol then cut and pasted back into the editor and it looked ok in html  (boxed in grey)

Comment: But you  realized that in this site it is assumed that the final goal is convert to TeX code compile it by a TeX engine, not to HTML code generated by R, right? `:D`

Comment: I am just the devils advocate The question is just like others as to how to use TeX to output to XXX (DVI PDF HTML MarkDown some come some go) the way to use the $\Beta$ is either uses a tex package to add a grey "highlight" OR to emulate the way this site/markdown works with such a verbatim environment then include it converted as if it will be done during compilation. hence the suggestion to pre-empt the tex-ps-pdf-html steps the final R output would be **without** `highlighting` <mi>&#x03B2;<!-- β --></mi> or with code tags to address the question needs to become  `<code>β</code>`

Comment: I have just seen this answer and comments. The first comment by KJO is a suitable answer to my question.

Comment: In fact, I tried the point 2 of this answer with \texttt and do not got anything printed.

Comment: @iago Your question is about to produce only a HTML page with R markdown? Because then, the question  should be closed as off-topic. Both points works perfectly  is you compile the Rmarkdown as PDF, because then is used  *LaTeX*  (pdflatex). However, for an HTML, MathJax (that is off-otpic here), is used to compile the math enviroment, but LaTeX is not used at all,  and therefore any other LaTeX command is ignored, including the contents of  `\textt{...}`, even if this include some math environment.  This is explained in the R markdown documentation.

Comment: Yes, it is. Beacuse of that reason, I also asked this question in the forum stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55382546/can-i-type-latex-or-other-special-symbols-inside-verbatim-code-in-rmarkdown, where I did not get any satisfactory answer). I did not know what you tell about MathJax, so thanks by the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `` `r paste0("$\\beta$ = ", mean(mtcars$mpg))` ``.

Comment: I do not get what I want., since it is not highlighted like verbatim code.